# have to I use the schema in options route when using validateInput/serializeInput

Tags: node.js, fastify

Must I put the schema object in route options when using validateInput/serzializeInput ?

```
fastify.post('/light-foo',
  async function handler (request, reply) {
    const validationResult = request.validateInput({ name: 'John' }, bodySchema)
    console.log(validationResult)

    const serializedResponse = reply.serializeInput({ user: { id: 1 } }, responseSchema)
    return serializedResponse
  })
```

in this code above is no options schema in route. Is this code at the bottom uneccessarry ?

```
fastify.post('/light-foo', schema,
  async function handler (request, reply) {
    const validationResult = request.validateInput({ name: 'John' }, bodySchema)
    console.log(validationResult)

    const serializedResponse = reply.serializeInput({ user: { id: 1 } }, responseSchema)
    return serializedResponse
  })
```